# Fitting distributions, goodness of fit, p-value. Is it possible to do this with Scipy (Python)?

Tags: distributions, python, p-value

INTRODUCTION: I'm a bioinformatician. In my analysis which I perform on all human genes (about 20 000) I search for a particular short sequence motif to check how many times this motif occurs in each gene.

Genes are 'written' in a linear sequence in four letters (A,T,G,C). For example: CGTAGGGGGTTTAC... This is the four-letter alphabet of genetic code which is like the secret language of each cell, it’s how DNA actually stores information.

I suspect that frequent repetations of a particular short motif sequence (AGTGGAC) in some genes are crucial in a specific biochemical process in the cell. Since the motif itself is very short it is difficult with computational tools to distinguish between true functional examples in genes and those that look similar by chance. To avoid this problem I get sequences of all genes and concatenated into a single string and shuffled. The length of each of the original genes was stored. Then for each of the original sequence lengths, a random sequence was constructed by repeatedly picking A or T or G or C at random from the concatenated sequence and transferring it to the random sequence. In this way, the resulting set of randomized sequences has the same length distribution, as well as the overall A,T,G,C composition. Then I search for the motif in these randomized sequences. I permormed this procedure 1000 times and averaged the results.

- 15000 genes that do not contain a given motif
- 5000 genes that contain 1 motif
- 3000 genes that contain 2 motifs
- 1000 genes that contain 3 motifs
- ...
- 1 gene that contain 6 motifs

So even after 1000 times randomization of true genetic code, there aren't any genes which have more than 6 motifs. But in the true genetic code, there are a few genes which contain more then 20 occurrences of the motif, which suggest that these repetition might be functional and it's unlikely to find them in such an abundance by pure chance.

PROBLEM: I would like to know the probability of finding a gene with let's say 20 occurences of the motif in my distribution. So I want to know the probability to find such a gene by chance. I would like to implement this in Python, but I don't know how.

Can I do such an analysis in Python?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Josh Sorry, I should have closed this earlier :-(

Comment: @mbq: Perhaps you can reconsider since four people (at the time I posted this) have up-voted it? It seems to be really a basic question of probability buried in a complex context (genetics), and being asked by someone who is an expert in a scientific field but not statistics perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

I am confident that you can code this in Python and there are likely to be multiple packages that will make the coding easier. I don't  know that I understand the true computational issue you face though. Perhaps if you include a code snippet showing how you are doing the 1,000 iteration randomization it would make things more concrete for someone like me lacking the genetics background.

The first thing that comes to mind though is a Monte Carlo sampling of your distribution. For example, use the [random_integers()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random_integers.html#numpy.random.random_integers) function in numpy to randomly select a motif out of your list of motifs. Add 1 to a counter if its length is equal to 20 otherwise don't count it. Do this thousands of times and your estimate of Prob(motif_length = 20) is counter / simulation_length.